# How to run a rdlc using coding

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset, reporting, rdlc

I have created an `rdlc` where I have used dataset taken as a new item in solution explorer for designing my report. After binding my report from that `datasource` which is named as `Dataset1`. I have created its object and tried to fill this `datasource` using coding. Now when I runs the following code I am not getting any result.

What can be the issue?

```
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
LocalReport localReport = reportViewer1.LocalReport;
localReport.DataSources.Clear();
localReport.ReportPath = @"E:\Projects\Manojp\AARFID_SSRS_Report\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Local Report\rptTest.rdlc";

// DataSet dataset = new DataSet("AARFID_Report");
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();

// fill the Data Set from DataBase.
//ds.Tables.Remove("M_GUEST");
ds.Tables.Clear();
GetData(ref ds);

//
// Create a report data source for the sales order data

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "AA";
rds.Value = ds.Tables[0];
localReport.DataSources.Add(rds); 
// reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds); 


reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
localReport.DataSources.Clear();
```

`GetData()` do this:

```
connection.Open();
ad.Fill(ds,"M_GUEST");
connection.Close();
```

In the report view a message is shown as:

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dtaset1_m_guest'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the names of datasets in the rdl file and the report generator match!

The easiest way would be to have a DataSet, DataSource and the instances named "M_GUEST". Also, do not clear the data sources before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
rds.Name = "AA";
```

must match the name of the data set defined in the report. In your case, that would be

```
rds.Name = "dtaset1_m_guest";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add .rdlc report in your project by wizard then by default it take dataset name as 'DataSet1' . Now if you want to bind dynamically new dataset then name of that dataset must be 'DataSet1'. Try change it and also check that Table[0] contains some data(Rows) for which DataType get matched with original dataType of 'DataSet1'. If DataType doesn't matches then data wont come in your ReportViewer. Try this code:-

```
string exeFolder = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Substring(0, (Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Length - 3);
string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"Reports\SessionReport.rdlc");
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

For more detail about .rdlc report(Core logic) refer following link
[How to create report (RDLC) without database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275801/how-to-create-report-rdlc-without-database)

Answer (score 0):

If the DataSource in binding is named "Dataset1" then the one you your in code should also name the same.

I add it like this works perfectly do this as below:

```
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Dataset1", ds.Tables[0]));
```