# how to bind datasource to a .rdlc report in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, rdlc

Friends , I have developed a simple application using c# , it has two rdlc reports

i used this below code to bind datasource to report viewer

```
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\reports\reports\Report1.rdlc";
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("customer", dt.Tables[0])) ;
 this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

But when the report is generated ,it is empty report no data will displayed , any opinion???

Comment: And does `dt.Tables[0]` really contain data? Also: is the data source in your report called `customer`?

Comment: @ marc_s - yes,I tested it with forloop the data is in dataset in customer table, what should be the reportDataSource name should be ?  Table name or dataset name? ` reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("customer", dt.Tables[0])) ;`

Comment: The name of the data source **inside your report** needs to be the same as the one you're using when calling `new ReportDataSource(....)` - if you call it `customer` when creating the `ReportDataSource`, the data source name inside the `.RDLC` report must also be `Customer`

Comment: @ marc_s - sorrry for the asking this , How to assign the `datasource` to `.RDLC` report ?

Answer (score 7):

When you add .rdlc report in your project by wizard then by default it take dataset name as **'DataSet1'** . Now if you want to bind dynamically new dataset then name of that dataset must be **'DataSet1'**. Try change it and also check that Table[0] contains some data(Rows) for which **DataType** get matched with original dataType of `DataSet1`. If DataType doesn't matches then data wont come in your ReportViewer. Try this code:-

```
string exeFolder = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Substring(0, (Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Length - 3);
string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"Reports\SessionReport.rdlc");
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", yourDataSet.Tables[0]);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

For more detail about .rdlc report(Core logic) refer following link
[How to create report (RDLC) without database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275801/how-to-create-report-rdlc-without-database)

Answer (score 2):

try below, may be the problem with data source name incorrect.

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(ds.DataSetName + "_" + ds.Tables[0].TableName, ds.Tables[0]));
```

you can check dataset name on the rdlc file content. check the name property of the dataset match with what you have given in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I update my data with object binding:
In the Form1.cs file:

```
private myClass m_products = new Products();
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.PaperBindingSource.DataSource = m_products.GetProducts();
```

The `this.PaperBindingSource.DataSource` is important.